# Renaming a whole folder content

Tags: bash, shell, awk, rename

I'm on OSX 10.9.2 (BASH 3.5) and I wanted to rename a whole folder content names. So I run a script and somehow ended with this:

```
s01eDavid.Letterman.2014.02.27.Stupid.Human.Tricks.x264-SWOLLED.mp4
s01eDavid.Letterman.2014.03.07.Lenny.Marcus.HDTV.x264-BATV.mp4
s01eDavid.Letterman.2014.03.24.Jimmy.Carter.HDTV.x264-SWOLLED.mp4
s01eDavid.Letterman.2014.03.25.Emma.Watson.720p.HDTV.x264-SWOLLED.mkv
```

(There is extra S01e at the beggining of each sentence while there was supposed to be the S01e01 , S01e02.....)

How can I remove/rename those files to make it look like that?:

```
s01e1 David.Letterman.2014.02.27.Stupid.Human.Tricks.x264-SWOLLED.mp4
s01e2 David.Letterman.2014.03.07.Lenny.Marcus.HDTV.x264-BATV.mp4
s01e3 David.Letterman.2014.03.24.Jimmy.Carter.HDTV.x264-SWOLLED.mp4
s01e4 David.Letterman.2014.03.25.Emma.Watson.720p.HDTV.x264-SWOLLED.mkv
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you determine the episode numbers?

Comment: @MauritzHansen Probably by date.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my script: https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/472a672311d8d80955a8

Answer (score 1):

Not an `awk` solution:

```
cnt=1
for f in *; do 
  fcnt=$(printf "%02d" $cnt)
  echo mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed -e "s/^s01e/&$fcnt /")"
  cnt=$(($cnt+1)); 
done
```

I made the episode number have 2 digits using the printf command.

This just prints the commands to stdout, so you can check whether you like the output. Remove the leading "echo" from line 4 when you want to rename for real.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  however... i get this message:/Users/rshloosh/unix_files/numbering.sh: line 9: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")  and only the first 8 lines are bing processed.. lines 9 and 10 ( last are not..)  this is how the folder looks like:

Comment: david.letterman.2014.04.24.neil.patrick.harris.720p.hdtv.x264-bajskorv.mkv
s01e08 08 david.letterman.2014.04.25.michael.j.fox.720p.hdtv.x264-bajskorv.mkv
s01edavid.letterman.2014.04.30.kiefer.sutherland.720p.hdtv.x264-bajskorv.mkv
s01edavid.letterman.2014.05.01.louis.c.k.720p.hdtv.x264-bajskorv.mkv

Comment: @user67486 Your error message should be gone now.. And I thought you had s01e in front of every file name; how do you expect other file names to be handled?

Comment: **i had s01e in front of every line ... after i run the script twice that was he result... iwould like to have s01eXX  where xx incremnet in the start of lines... **

Answer (score 0):

```
episode=1
for x in s01e*; do
  mv "$x" "s01e$episode ${x#s01e}"
  episode=$((episode+1))
done
```

If there are 10 or more episodes, you may prefer to have a leading 0 for numbers up to 9. An easy trick for that is to generate numbers in the range 100–199 and trim the leading 1 digit.

```
episode=101
for x in s01e*; do
  mv "$x" "s01e${episode#1} ${x#s01e}"
  episode=$((episode+1))
done
```